# YouTube API v3.0: How do you determine if a video is 'pay-per-view'?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the `YouTube Python API` (v3.0) to query YouTube with specific video IDs, and I would like to know which ones of the videos listed in the results are paid-content (there are some TV-shows in there).

I have gone through the 'video' object parameters (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), but I have not been able to find anything useful:

- 'contentDetails.licensedContent' flag does not seem to match non-free videos
- 'status.license' seems to be almost always set to 'youtube'
- 'status.embeddable' also does not seem to depend on free/not-free

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no field in the `youtube#video` object that represents whether a specific video costs money. You could use a rough proxy, like the presence of `youtube#video.contentRating`, as a clue that the video might be something that's television/film content, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's paid content.

Comment: too bad there is no such field. Do you know if it will ever be included in the API? I guess I will ignore this parameter for know. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request via the method described at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html

Comment: I have filed a feature request for this (thanks for the tip): https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5218