# How to detect youtube pay videos using api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to know whether a video is free or paid?
What property is indicates videos which needs Payment?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWu03qUnHlk

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/9J_Rsvw1p9XGci8Ne9GRDP6m6NE\"",
  "id": "wWu03qUnHlk",
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1H11M51S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
      "allowed": [
        "US"
      ]
    },
    "projection": "rectangular"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such feature in the Youtube API. All the video properties are found in [Youtube Resource Representation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) and there's no property that indicates if it's paid or not.

This is confirmed by a Google Engineer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729300/6143482).